# Upvote not showing after edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, voting, down-votes, up-votes

Steps to reproduce (as a user with low enough rep to get step 3):

1. Upvote an answer.
2. Edit the answer you just upvoted.
3. After the edit, the answer displays with a header message "**Thanks for your edit!** This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed."
4. At this point, the upvote I just entered is no longer shown, and I wonder if it registered or if it's cancelled out somehow.  I upvote again, on the answer which seems to me to be improved, and the number doesn't change- indicating that this is just a display error.

The expected behavior is that at steps 3-4, the upvote I cast in step 1 would still be visible.

This does not appear to happen on a second edit to the same post, made after the first edit is approved (reloading the answer to see that, but not the whole page).